# Coroutine does no play all the way through

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, lerp

Unfortunately my co routine does not play all the way through. It is supposed to fade an object so it's alpha is 0. However it fades to  .039.

```
{
    StartCoroutine(colorlerpin7());
    yield return null;
}

public IEnumerator colorlerpin7()

{
    float ElapsedTime = 0.0f;
    float TotalTime = 1f;
    while (ElapsedTime < TotalTime)

    {
        //  fades out atipical
        ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        fluidpef.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(new 
        Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f), new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f), (ElapsedTime / 
        TotalTime));
        yield return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like the "correct" behaviour since your ElapsedTime will be bigger then TotalTime before you will get to an alpha of 0 (or a lerp value of 1) e.g.

->frame x ElapsedTime is 0.97 your lerp value is 0.97.

->frame x+1 ElapsedTime might be already 1.1, so you will jump out of the loop.

Just add this code after the loop:

```
fluidpef.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(new 
    Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f), new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f), 1);
```

Comment: In this case you won't even need the Lerp function though, you could just force the value to `new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f)`

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` condition is why the alpha value does not decrease to 0. `ElapsedTime < TotalTime` means that in your loop `ElapsedTime / TotalTime` will never be equal to 1, meaning that the value of alpha will not be 0.

To solve it I would change the condition to check the alpha value of the material:

```
public IEnumerator colorlerpin7()

{
    float ElapsedTime = 0.0f;
    float TotalTime = 1f;
    Renderer matRenderer =  fluidpef.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    while (matRenderer.material.color.a > 0.0f)

    {
        ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        matRenderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(new 
        Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f), new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f), (ElapsedTime / 
        TotalTime);
        yield return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: `Color.Lerp` will do clamp for you.

Comment: `Color.Lerp` clamps the third paramenter, not the color value, so your code will get the same result as the OP's. I think his problem is not about the clamp.

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry for the trouble. The problem, as already noted, is in the `while` that ends a frame too early. In this answer I change the condition to check on the alpha value instead of the `ElapsedTime`